# pug meta TypeError: Cannot read property '(' of undefined - running on Heroku

Tags: heroku, pug, meta

I having very curious issues on this simple pug code when deployed on **heroku**.

Using "pug": "2.0.0-rc.4"
node 8.1.4, npm 5.0.3

Locally works fine.

```
doctype html
  html
    head
      title= "hello"
      meta(charset="UTF-8")
    body

      h1 hello
```

I run some tests and the issue is with meta tag.
If I just cut the line it runs.

Any idea?

Error stack

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property '(' of undefined
  at Lexer.bracketExpression (/app/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:212:40)
  at Lexer.attrs (/app/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1011:24)
  at Lexer.callLexerFunction (/app/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1319:23)
  at Lexer.advance (/app/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1356:15)
  at Lexer.callLexerFunction (/app/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1319:23)
  at Lexer.getTokens (/app/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:1375:12)
  at lex (/app/node_modules/pug-lexer/index.js:12:42)
  at Object.lex (/app/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:99:27)
  at Function.loadString [as string] (/app/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:44:24)
  at compileBody (/app/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:86:18)
```

Comment: check your spacing

Answer (score 1):

The position of the indent after html seems to be different.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= "hello"
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
  body

    h1 hello
```

Answer (score 0):

After losing 6 hours on this I just tested different version of pug and node together.

With this setup everything worked again, on heroku too:

**"pug": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"node": "8.1.4"**

Hope this helps other getting into this stupid nightmare